# Meeting workspace: how do I easily move library and list objects from one week to another?

Tags: meeting-workspace, libraries

I'm using a Meeting Workspace in SharePoint. On the default landing page, I have uploaded some documents for a meeting. However, we weren't able to address the documents in that week's meeting.

Is there an easy way to move the documents from one week to the next week? The same function would be useful for list items as well. So far, all I can do is delete the documents from the current week and repost them to another week.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any easy way directly in SharePoint to do this, but I did find an easy way to move the files using Windows Explorer.

1. Map your SharePoint site as a network drive. Instead of specifying a network folder, click "Connect to a Web site"... and provide the web address of your SharePoint site.
2. Navigate to your Meeting Workspace and enter your document library.
3. Choose the folder that holds the files you want to move. Cut them from that location.
4. Navigate to the folder where you want to move the files. Paste them into that location.

Nice thing is, when I did this, all the metadata was included with the objects.